# Possible to call HtmlHelp API and pass ownership to another process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am calling HtmlHelp from process B and passing the HWND of another process (process A, the process that launched the current process B) to try and tie the help window to my parent process (A).

My process (B) then exits but this still causes the HTML help window to exit too. **How do I avoid the help viewer from exiting and have it linked to the lifetime of process A?**

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms670172(v=vs.85).aspx)

> hwndCaller
>   Specifies the handle (hwnd) of the window calling HtmlHelp(). The help window is owned by this window.
>   When the help window is closed, HtmlHelp() will return focus to the owner unless the owner is the desktop.

The API call is simply;

`HtmlHelpA(procWindow, "hlp.chm", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, help_pointer);`

Background:

I have a very old Fortran program that launches winhelp (old help format) which I am migrating to HtmlHelp (newer API and format). I am unable to call the Win32 HtmlHelp API directly from this old code because it hangs (caused by the stack size and location, something I can't change).

To bypass this I am shelling out to a new process from the Fortran code which then has a default stack size which can successfully launch help.

The help proxy code is compiled using the SilverFrost C compiler so that it won't introduce any more dependencies (the main app is SilverFrost Fortran).

Comment: Have process (B) **not exit**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help window is displayed by the `hhctrl.ocx` module that is loaded into the process that calls the function `HtmlHelp` exported by `hhctrl.ocx`. What this means is that the help window cannot outlive the process that called `HtmlHelp`. Because when that process terminates, its windows are destroyed, its modules are unloaded.

There are some ways for you to handle this:

1. Don't use the `HtmlHelp` function and instead use the help viewer process `hh.exe` to host the help file.
2. Arrange process A to make the call to `HtmlHelp`.
3. Have a different process make the call to `HtmlHelp`, which is the approach that you currently use.
4. Ensure that process B outlives process A.

Comment: Thanks, HH.exe nearly does the job, it's just missing the ability to search by keyword (so I don't have to upgrade all of the old help links). This tool looks like it did the job but now appears to have been infected. http://keyworks.helpmvp.com/home/keyhh . Option 2 is not possible due to the existing Fortran codebase.